# Remembering selected dropdown values Python/Flask

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

```
            <option value="1" {{ selected }}>1</option>
            <option value="2" {{ selected }}>2</option>
            <option value="3" {{ selected }}>3</option>
            <option value="4" {{ selected }}>4</option>
```

I have a flask app with a handful of dropdown menus. I want to pass the selected value when a user submits the form so they see their previous selection on the next page.

Could someone provide a simple example of this? I just cant conceptualize how to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python Flask view

```
@app.route('/form/')
def form():
    # list of tuples representing select options
    choices = [(str(x), str(x)) for x in range(1, 20)]
    # test if value was passed in (e.g. GET method), default value is 1
    selected = request.args.get('choice', '1')
    # application 'state' variable with default value and test
    state = {'choice': selected}
    return render_template('view_form.html', choices=choices, state=state)
```

Within Jinja template:

```
{% for row in choices %}
<option value="{{ row[0] }}"{% if row[0] == state.choice %} selected{% endif %}>{{ row[1] }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this and when I select any option, submit the form, the next page resets the selection to 1.

Comment: it works when changing this:

    selected = str((request.form['choz']))  #selected = request.args.get('choice', '1')

Comment: @abigperson I have a question on dropdown using Flask and python too. Mind helping me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628274/unable-to-get-value-selected-in-python-from-a-dropdown-using-flask